# 'ggplot2' - and other libraries - work in R Console, but can't access them from python

Tags: python, r, subprocess, anaconda, rpy2

I have R 3.3.0 on Mac Yosemite 10.10.5 and Python 2.7.11 and rpy2 2.7.0.

ggplot2 is installed in R Console and my R script - additional_plots.R - works perfectly in R Console.

However, I need to run the script additional_plots.R from Python (because all of my other code is in Python). When I run:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
```

My error message is:

```
/Users/chriseal/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/robject.py:6: UserWarning: Warning: rpy2.rinterface.initr()

/Users/chriseal/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/robject.py:6: UserWarning:  namespace ‘ggplot2’ is not available and has been replaced by .GlobalEnv when processing object ‘p1’

/Users/chriseal/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/robject.py:6: UserWarning:  namespace ‘scales’ is not available and has been replaced by .GlobalEnv when processing object ‘p3’

rpy2.rinterface.initr()
```

I have also tried:

```
import subprocess
retcode = subprocess.call(['RScript','additional_plots.R'])
```

And received an error that references ggplot2, saying that it isn't installed.

I have tried installing 'ggplot2' within rpy2, and it installs with no errors, but when I try to run additional_plots.R, I get an error saying 'ggplot2' isn't available.

I don't understand why ggplot2 is installed in R Console, but can't be accessed via Python. How do I access ggplot2 - or furthermore, ensure that I can access all libraries available in R Console - from Python?

Thanks!!
Chris

Edit: It appears I have R 3.3.0 in R Console and R 3.2.2 is what is used via Terminal. How can I upgrade the version of R in Terminal to 3.3.0? The CRAN R-3.3.0.pkg doesn't seem to update the version referenced via Terminal.

Comment: The child process created with `subprocess.call` appears to have a different starting environment than its parent process (you start Python from), and as you note it this results in both using different version of R. This is almost certainly something linked to anaconda (feature, or something local to your installation).

Comment: @Igautier "This is almost certainly something linked to anaconda (feature, or something local to your installation)." How can I reinstall/upgrade R to ensure that R 3.3.0 is called from both R Console and Terminal?

Comment: I am not a regular anaconda user and I am unable to help further.

Comment: @Igautier, I fixed it by downloading and installing R-3.2.4-revised.pkg from the old link on the CRAN site. Must be something with the versions not lining up. 'import subprocess; retcode = subprocess.call(['RScript','additional_plots.R'])' worked from there. Thanks for your help!!